# Remove text decoration from ActionLink

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to remove the text decoration from the following however text-decoration: none doesnt seem to work. Please could anyone give me some pointers?

```
<h1>The<br/>@Html.ActionLink("World Wide Web", "WWW", new { @class = "NameStyle" })</h1>
```

My CSS:

```
.NameStyle
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: What text decoration does it have?  What other styles might be affecting it? Have you tried inspecting the link in your browser's developer tools to see what styles are being applied(e.g. right click and "inspect element" in chrome/safari, using FireBug in firefox etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct overload of the ActionLink helper and thus you haven't applied any CSS class to it.

Here's the overload that you used:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "World Wide Web",                // linkText
    "WWW",                           // actionName
    new { @class = "NameStyle" }     // routeValues
)
```

and here's the markup it generated:

```
<a href="/Home/WWW?class=NameStyle">World Wide Web</a>
```

I think you understand why this doesn't work as you might expect it to work.

And here's the correct overload that you should use:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "World Wide Web",                // linkText
    "WWW",                           // actionName
    null,                            // routeValues
    new { @class = "NameStyle" }     // htmlAttributes
)
```

which generates:

```
<a class="NameStyle" href="/Home/WWW">World Wide Web</a>
```

Now your `.NameStyle` class definition might actually be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong overload.

Right now you're passing the CSS class in the RouteValues parameter.

Try

```
@Html.ActionLink("World Wide Web", "WWW", null, new { @class = "NameStyle" })
```